# How to change package manager used with Angular CLI (e.g. using pnpm instead of npm for `ng add`)?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, pnpm

Did not find much, yet for that topic, therefore using SO-question.

For commands like e.g. `ng add @angular/material` I would like to use the package manager of choice `pnpm`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As simple as it sounds ;)

```
ng config -g cli.packageManager pnpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instruction:
ng config -g cli.packageManager pnpm

or

You can add the configuration inside angular-config.json file

In **Windows**:

%USERPROFILE%\angular-config.json
or
C:\users\USERNAME-GOES-HERE\angular-config.json

In **Linux**:

~/.angular-config.json

---

The file has a content like this:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics",
    "packageManager": "yarn",
    "warnings": {
      "versionMismatch": false
    }
  }
}
```

Inside "cli" node, add the instruction: packageManager: pnpm

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "212b0653-b7ad-460f-9687-fddb7fba2fe9",
    "completion": {
      "prompted": true
    },
    "packageManager": "pnpm"
  }
}
```